# Using .select or .map to get an array of names from an activerecord model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am trying to get an array of names from an activerecord model based on a search query.

I have this method in my item model.

```
def self.search(search)
    if search
      where(['lower(name) LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
    else
      Item.all
    end
  end
```

I am trying to figure out the difference between using these two lines they are both returning the same thing.

`Item.search('ex').select('name').map(&:name)` vs
`Item.search('ex').map(&:name)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically what `.select` does is what we call a **projection**, which is filtering the fields that are returned by the query. However, if you do not call `.select` at all, Rails default to selecting all the fields from the table.

So the diference between `Item.search('ex').select('name')` and `Item.search('ex')` is that the former selects only the column **name** and the latter selects all the columns from the **items** table.
Given that, when you map all the items to grab only the name, it doesn't make any diference, since both ways of doing have **name** selected.

Answer (score 12):

```
Item.search('ex').select('name').map(&:name)
```

In the above statement, you are selecting only the `name` column from the result of `Item.search('ex')` and then getting the names for all of them using `.map(&:name)`.

But, in the follwing statement:

```
Item.search('ex').map(&:name)
```

You are not selecting the `name` column, just getting the names using `.map(&:name)` from the result of `Item.search('ex')`.

And Yes, they return the exact same result.

So, if you want the array of names only from the search result, then selecting the name column is redundant. Just go with this:

```
Item.search('ex').map(&:name)
```

Or, even better, do it using [pluck](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck):

```
Item.search('ex').pluck(:name)
```

It bypasses the need for instantiating every `ActiveRecord` object, and instead just returns the queried values in an `Array` directly, which improves performance both in terms of execution time and memory consumption.

Answer (score 0):

> **1st Query:** `Item.search('ex').select('name').map(&:name)`

Let's take the entire statement piece by piece.

```
Item.search('ex') # it trigger one SQL query and return `ActiveRecord::Relation` object in Array

 SELECT `items`.* FROM `items` WHERE (lower(name) LIKE '%ex%')
```

**Next**

```
Item.search('ex').select('name')
 SELECT `items`.`name` FROM `items` WHERE (lower(name) LIKE '%ex%')
```

As we might can see it return `ActiveRecord::Relation` object in `Array` with selecting `name` fields.

**Now**

```
Item.search('ex').select('name').map(&:name)

SELECT `items`.`name` FROM `items` WHERE (lower(name) LIKE '%ex%')
```

Further here as you are calling `#map` method on `ActiveRecord::Relation` object which itself defined in [Enumerable Module](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html).

> `#map` Returns a new array with the results of running block once for
>   every element in enum.

---

> **2nd Query:** `Item.search('ex').map(&:name)`

```
SELECT `items`.* FROM `items` WHERE (lower(name) LIKE '%ex%')
```

Here you are calling`#map` method on `ActiveRecord::Relation` object. Further you are saying, " Hey `ActiveRecord::Relation` I need only name field from search object, and `ActiveRecord::Relation` replay back to give all name in form of array. "

For more information [The clever hack that makes `items.map(&:name)` work](http://blog.honeybadger.io/how-ruby-ampersand-colon-works/).

Hope this help !!!